# Problems with adding wishlist in .net+blazor ecommerce app

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

`In swagger the wishlist is retrieved,items are added and deleted succesfully but when i press the button on product page nothing happens  WISHLIST SERVICE ON SERVER

```
namespace BlazorEcommerce.Server.Services.WishlistService
{
public class WishlistService : IWishlistService
{
private readonly DataContext \_context;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor \_httpContextAccessor;

        public WishlistService(DataContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _context = context;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>> AddToWishlist(int productId, int userId)
        {
            try
            {
               
                        // Print the userId to the console to see what value is being used
                        Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to add productId {productId} to wishlist for userId BACKEND {userId}");
    
                        // Check if the product is already in the wishlist
                        var existingWishlistItem = await _context.Wishlists
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.ProductId == productId && w.UserId == userId);
    
                        if (existingWishlistItem != null)
                {
                    // Product is already in the wishlist
                    return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist>
                    {
                        Success = false,
                        Message = "Product is already in the wishlist.",
                        Data = existingWishlistItem
                    };
                }
    
                var wishlistItem = new Wishlist
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    ProductId = productId,
                    DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow
                };
    
                _context.Wishlists.Add(wishlistItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
                return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist> { Data = wishlistItem };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while adding to the wishlist."
                };
            }
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<bool>> RemoveFromWishlist(int productId, int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var wishlistItem = await _context.Wishlists
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(w => w.ProductId == productId && w.UserId == userId);
    
                if (wishlistItem == null)
                {
                    // Product is not in the wishlist
                    return new ServiceResponse<bool>
                    {
                        Success = false,
                        Message = "Product not found in the wishlist.",
                        Data = false
                    };
                }
    
                _context.Wishlists.Remove(wishlistItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
                return new ServiceResponse<bool> { Data = true };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<bool>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while removing from the wishlist.",
                    Data = false
                };
            }
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Wishlist>>> GetUserWishlist(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var wishlist = await _context.Wishlists
                    .Where(w => w.UserId == userId)
                    .Include(w => w.Product)
                    .ToListAsync();
    
                return new ServiceResponse<List<Wishlist>> { Data = wishlist };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<List<Wishlist>>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while fetching the wishlist."
                };
            }
        }
    }

}
```

WISHLIST CONTROLLER

```
using BlazorEcommerce.Server.Services.WishlistService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

\[ApiController\]
\[Route("api/\[controller\]")\]
public class WishlistController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IWishlistService \_wishlistService;

    public WishlistController(IWishlistService wishlistService)
    {
        _wishlistService = wishlistService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wishlistService));
    }
    
    [HttpPost("add/{userId}/{productId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddToWishlist(int userId, int productId)
    {
        var result = await _wishlistService.AddToWishlist(productId, userId);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    
    [HttpDelete("remove/{userId}/{productId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveFromWishlist(int userId, int productId)
    {
        var result = await _wishlistService.RemoveFromWishlist(productId, userId);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    
    [HttpGet("user/{userId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserWishlist(int userId)
    {
        var result = await _wishlistService.GetUserWishlist(userId);
        return Ok(result);
    }

}
```

WISHLIST SERVICE ON CLIENT

```
using BlazorEcommerce.Shared;

namespace BlazorEcommerce.Client.Services.WishlistService
{
public class WishlistService:IWishlistService
{
private readonly HttpClient \_http;
private List\<Wishlist\> wishlist;

        public WishlistService(HttpClient http)
        {
            _http = http;
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>> GetWishlist(int productId, int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>>(
                    $"api/wishlist/user/{{userId}}"
                );
    
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while fetching the wishlist.",
                };
            }
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>> AddToWishlist(int productId, int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>>(
                    $"api/wishlist/add/{{userId}}/{{productId}}", null
                );
    
                var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>>();
    
                // Check if the request was successful
                if (result.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Product with ID {productId} added to the wishlist.");
    
                    // Optionally, you can refresh the wishlist here
                    var wishlistResponse = await GetUserWishlist(userId);
                    wishlist = wishlistResponse?.Data;
                }
    
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while adding to the wishlist.",
                };
            }
        }
    
    
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<Wishlist>> RemoveFromWishlist(int productId, int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _http.DeleteAsync($"api/wishlist/remove/{{userId}}/{{productId}}");
    
                return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist>
                {
                    Success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode,
                    Message = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "Item removed from wishlist." : "Failed to remove item from wishlist."
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<Wishlist>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while removing from the wishlist.",
                };
            }
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<Wishlist>>> GetUserWishlist(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<List<Wishlist>>>(
                    $"api/wishlist/user/{{userId}}"
                );
    
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new ServiceResponse<List<Wishlist>>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "An error occurred while fetching the wishlist.",
                };
            }
        }
    }

}
```

PROFILE PAGE WHERE I WANT THE WISHLIST DISPLAYED

```
@page "/profile"
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@inject BlazorEcommerce.Client.Services.WishlistService.IWishlistService WishlistService
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@attribute \[Authorize\]


    <h3>Hi! You're logged in with <i>@context.User.Identity.Name</i>.</h3>


<h5>Delivery Address</h5>

<p></p>

<h5>Wishlist</h5>
@if (wishlist != null && wishlist.Any())
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in wishlist)
        {
            <li>@item.Product.Title</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <p>Your wishlist is empty.</p>
}

<h5>Change Password</h5>


    
    
        New Password
        
         request.Password)" /\>
    
    
        Confirm New Password
        
         request.ConfirmPassword)" /\>
    
    Apply


@message

@code {
UserChangePassword request = new UserChangePassword();
List\<Wishlist\> wishlist;
string message = string.Empty;
int userId;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the authentication state
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
    
            // Check if the user is authenticated
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var email = user.Identity.Name; // Assuming the email is stored as the username
    
                // Call the API to get the user ID by email
                userId = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<int>($"/api/user/getid?email={email}");
    
                Console.WriteLine($"User ID from API: {userId}");
    
                // Fetch the wishlist for the user
                var wishlistResponse = await WishlistService.GetUserWishlist(userId);
    
                // Other code...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions appropriately
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    
    private async Task ChangePassword()
    {
        var result = await AuthService.ChangePassword(request);
        message = result.Message;
    }

}
```

PRODUCTDETAILS PAGE WHERE THE BUTTON TO ADD TO WISHLIST IS

```
@page "/product/{id:int}"
@using BlazorEcommerce.Client.Services.WishlistService;
@inject IProductService ProductService
@inject ICartService CartService
@inject IWishlistService WishlistService

@if (product == null)
{
\<span\>@message\</span\>
}
else
{
\<div class="media"\>
\<div class="media-img-wrapper mr-2"\>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(product.ImageUrl))
{
<img alt="@product.Title" src="@product.ImageUrl" />
}
else
{
\<MudCarousel Class="mud-width-full" ItemsSource="@product.Images" Style="height: 200px;"\>
\<ItemTemplate\>
\<MudImage Src="@context.Data"\>\</MudImage\>\>
\</ItemTemplate\>
\</MudCarousel\>
}
\</div\>
\<div class="media-body"\>
<h2 class="mb-0">@product.Title</h2>
<p>@product.Description</p>
@if (product.Variants != null && product.Variants.Count \> 1)
{
\<div class="mb-3"\>
\<select class="form-select" @bind="currentTypeId"\>
@foreach (var variant in product.Variants)
{
\<option value="@variant.ProductTypeId"\>@variant.ProductType.Name\</option\>
}
\</select\>
\</div\>
}
@if (GetSelectedVariant() != null)
{
@if (GetSelectedVariant().OriginalPrice \> GetSelectedVariant().Price)
{
<h6 class="text-muted original-price">
$@GetSelectedVariant().OriginalPrice
</h6>
}
<h4 class="price">
$@GetSelectedVariant().Price
</h4>
}
\<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddToCart"\>
   Add to Cart
\</button\>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick="AddToWishlist" disabled="@productInWishlist">
                <i class="oi oi-heart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@(productInWishlist ? "Added to Wishlist" : "Add to Wishlist")
            </button>
    
        </div>
    </div>

}

@code {
private Product? product = null;
private string message = string.Empty;
private int currentTypeId = 1;
int userId;
bool productInWishlist;

    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        message = "Loading product...";
    
        var result = await ProductService.GetProduct(Id);
        if (!result.Success)
        {
            message = result.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            product = result.Data;
            if (product.Variants.Count > 0)
            {
                currentTypeId = product.Variants[0].ProductTypeId;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private ProductVariant GetSelectedVariant()
    {
        var variant = product.Variants.FirstOrDefault(v => v.ProductTypeId == currentTypeId);
        return variant;
    }
    
    private async Task AddToCart()
    {
        var productVariant = GetSelectedVariant();
        var cartItem = new CartItem
            {
                ProductId = productVariant.ProductId,
                ProductTypeId = productVariant.ProductTypeId
            };
    
        await CartService.AddToCart(cartItem);
    }
    
    
    private async Task AddToWishlist()
    {
        if (product != null)
        {
            var result = await WishlistService.AddToWishlist(product.Id, userId);
            Console.WriteLine($"Add to Wishlist Result: {result.Success}, Message: {result.Message}");
    
            if (result.Success)
            {
                productInWishlist = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the error or show a message
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {result.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

AUTHENTICATION SERVICE ON SERVER

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens; using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; using System.Security.Claims; using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace BlazorEcommerce.Server.Services.AuthService {
    public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthService(DataContext context,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public int GetUserId() => int.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        public string GetUserEmail() => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            var response = new ServiceResponse<string>();
            var user = await _context.Users
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()));
            if (user == null)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "User not found.";
            }
            else if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "Wrong password.";
            }
            else
            {
                response.Data = CreateToken(user);
            }

            return response;
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(User user, string password)
        {
            if (await UserExists(user.Email))
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<int>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User already exists."
                };
            }

            CreatePasswordHash(password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new ServiceResponse<int> { Data = user.Id, Message = "Registration successful!" };
        }

        public async Task<bool> UserExists(string email)
        {
            if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(user => user.Email.ToLower()
                 .Equals(email.ToLower())))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac
                    .ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }

        private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
            {
                var computedHash =
                    hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                return computedHash.SequenceEqual(passwordHash);
            }
        }

        private string CreateToken(User user)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    signingCredentials: creds);

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<bool>> ChangePassword(int userId, string newPassword)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<bool>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User not found."
                };
            }

            CreatePasswordHash(newPassword, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new ServiceResponse<bool> { Data = true, Message = "Password has been changed." };
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            return await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email.Equals(email));
        }
    } }
```

AUTHENTICATION SERVICE ON CLIENT

```
namespace BlazorEcommerce.Client.Services.AuthService
{
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
private readonly HttpClient \_http;
private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider \_authStateProvider;

        public AuthService(HttpClient http, AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider)
        {
            _http = http;
            _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<bool>> ChangePassword(UserChangePassword request)
        {
            var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/change-password", request.Password);
            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<bool>>();
        }
    
        public async Task<bool> IsUserAuthenticated()
        {
            return (await _authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> GetUserId(string email)
        {
            var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<int>>($"api/auth/getUserId?email={email}");
            return result;
        }
    
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(UserLogin request)
        {
            var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", request);
            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<string>>();
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(UserRegister request)
        {
            var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/register", request);
            return await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<int>>();
        }
    }

}
AUTHENTICATION SERVICE ON SERVER
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace BlazorEcommerce.Server.Services.AuthService
{
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
private readonly DataContext \_context;
private readonly IConfiguration \_configuration;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor \_httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthService(DataContext context,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    
        public int GetUserId() => int.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        public string GetUserEmail() => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<string>> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            var response = new ServiceResponse<string>();
            var user = await _context.Users
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()));
            if (user == null)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "User not found.";
            }
            else if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "Wrong password.";
            }
            else
            {
                response.Data = CreateToken(user);
            }
    
            return response;
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(User user, string password)
        {
            if (await UserExists(user.Email))
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<int>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User already exists."
                };
            }
    
            CreatePasswordHash(password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);
    
            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
    
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
            return new ServiceResponse<int> { Data = user.Id, Message = "Registration successful!" };
        }
    
        public async Task<bool> UserExists(string email)
        {
            if (await _context.Users.AnyAsync(user => user.Email.ToLower()
                 .Equals(email.ToLower())))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac
                    .ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }
    
        private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
            {
                var computedHash =
                    hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                return computedHash.SequenceEqual(passwordHash);
            }
        }
    
        private string CreateToken(User user)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
            };
    
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));
    
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
    
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    signingCredentials: creds);
    
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    
            return jwt;
        }
    
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<bool>> ChangePassword(int userId, string newPassword)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.FindAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<bool>
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User not found."
                };
            }
    
            CreatePasswordHash(newPassword, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);
    
            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
    
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
            return new ServiceResponse<bool> { Data = true, Message = "Password has been changed." };
        }
    
        public async Task<User> GetUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            return await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email.Equals(email));
        }
    }

}
```

THE WISHLIST CAN BE SEEN ONLY WHEN THE USER IS AUTHENTICATED
WISHLIST MODEL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorEcommerce.Shared
{
public class Wishlist
{
public int Id { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
    
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
        // Navigation properties for foreign keys
        public User User { get; set; }
    
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

}
```

PLEASE HELP SO I CAN MAKE THE FRONTEND COMMUNICATION WITH THE BACKEND TO WORK FOR ADDING A WISHLIST IN MY ECOMMERCE APP BECAUSE NOW THAT BUTTON DOES NOT ADD THE PRODUCT TO DATABASE AND THE PROFILE PAGE DOES NOT CONTAIN THE PRODUCTS FROM WISHLIST BUT WHEN I ADD REMOVE OR DISPLAY THE WISHLIST WITH SWAGGER IT WORKS